# Использование значения одной переменной в двух триггерах

Tags: oracle, plsql, триггер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли задать значение переменной в триггере типа: `before update`, а затем использовать это же значение переменной в другом триггере типа: `after update`?
Если это возможно поделитесь примером, пожалуйста. Поискал в нэте так и не смог найти ничего.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вопрос закрыт, разобрался сам

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 4):

```
create or replace package myvars is value number; end myvars;
/
```

`myvars.value` записывайте и читайте в триггерах. Можно сетеры и гетеры добавить.

Ахтунг! При откате последнее состояние сохранится и возможно будет больше недействительно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, примерно сделал также. Опишу также свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Создал пакет, в спецификации пакета определил две переменные table type, затем в одном из триггеров заношу значения в переменные и использую их в другом.
Пример пакета:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EDS.my_pack IS

TYPE updated_id IS TABLE OF NUMBER
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

id_type updated_id; --обязательно создать экземпляр, id_type затем используется в триггере

TYPE new_rule_value IS TABLE OF NUMBER
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

rule_type new_rule_value; --обязательно создать экземпляр, затем rule_type используется в триггере

END my_pack;
```

Задаю значения переменных в первом триггере:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EDS.BFR_ROW_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON eds.parent_child
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

eds.my_pack.id_type(1) := :OLD.CHILD_ID; --так задаю значения для переменных
eds.my_pack.rule_type(1) := :NEW.RULE_COLUMN;

END;
```

Использую значения переменных во втором триггере:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EDS.AFTER_UPD_STMNT

AFTER UPDATE ON eds.parent_child
DECLARE

i1 number;
i2 number;

BEGIN

i1 := eds.my_pack.id_type(1); --так получаю значения переменных
i2 := eds.my_pack.rule_type(1);

eds.sign_pack.update_parents(i1, i2); --передаю эти значения в процедуру

END;
```

Comment: В after триггере i1, i2, если дальше не используются, можете вообще не объявлять, а в вызове функции использовать переменные из my_pack.

Comment: А зачем вообще такое решение нужно? Оба триггера на одну и туже таблицу, первый построчный, второй нет. Как то всё ненадёжно выглядит. Или это просто потренироваться?

Comment: Для иерархического запроса, в процедуре которую я вызываю, я использую иерархический запрос с обновление "потомков" и "родителей". А переменные действительно можно убрать, они от моих предыдущих попыток остались

Comment: Продумайте ещё раз дизайн, всегда лучше два апдейта в одном теле, чем последуюший апдейт в триггере предыдушего.